# Syntaxnet Turkish Language Data Set Non Existent Map Files

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, deep-learning, syntaxnet

I am new to Syntaxnet and i tried to use pre-trained model of Turkish language through the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md)

**Point-1 :** Although I set the MODEL_DIRECTORY environment variable, tokenize.sh didn't find the related path and it gives error like below :

```
root@4562a2ee0202:/opt/tensorflow/models/syntaxnet# echo "Eray eve geldi." | syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal/tokenize.sh
F syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:62] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::Env::Default()->NewRandomAccessFile(filename, &file)) (OK vs. **Not found: label-map**)
```

**Point-2 :** So, I changed the tokenize.sh through commenting the MODEL_DIR=$1 and set my Turkish language model path like below to go on :

```
PARSER_EVAL=bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval
CONTEXT=syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal/context.pbtxt
INPUT_FORMAT=stdin-untoken
MODEL_DIR=$1
MODEL_DIR=syntaxnet/models/etiya-smart-tr
```

**Point-3 :** After that when I run it as told, it gives error like below :

```
root@4562a2ee0202:/opt/tensorflow/models/syntaxnet# echo "Eray eve geldi" | syntaxnet/models/parsey_universal/tokenize.sh
I syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:101] Loaded 29 terms from syntaxnet/models/etiya-smart-tr/label-map.
I syntaxnet/embedding_feature_extractor.cc:35] Features: input.char input(-1).char input(1).char; input.digit input(-1).digit input(1).digit; input.punctuation-amount input(-1).punctuation-amount input(1).punctuation-amount 
I syntaxnet/embedding_feature_extractor.cc:36] Embedding names: chars;digits;puncts
I syntaxnet/embedding_feature_extractor.cc:37] Embedding dims: 16;16;16
F syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:62] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::Env::Default()->NewRandomAccessFile(filename, &file)) (OK vs. **Not found: syntaxnet/models/etiya-smart-tr/char-map**)
```

I had downloaded the Turkish package through tracing the link pattern indicated like download.tensorflow.org/models/parsey_universal/.zip
 and my language mapping file list like below :

- -rw-r----- 1 root root    50646 Sep 22 07:24 char-ngram-map

  -rw-r----- 1 root root      329 Sep 22 07:24 label-map

  -rw-r----- 1 root root   133477 Sep 22 07:24 morph-label-set

  -rw-r----- 1 root root  5553526 Sep 22 07:24 morpher-params

  -rw-r----- 1 root root     1810 Sep 22 07:24 morphology-map

  -rw-r----- 1 root root 10921546 Sep 22 07:24 parser-params

  -rw-r----- 1 root root    39990 Sep 22 07:24 prefix-table

  -rw-r----- 1 root root    28958 Sep 22 07:24 suffix-table

  -rw-r----- 1 root root      561 Sep 22 07:24 tag-map

  -rw-r----- 1 root root  5234212 Sep 22 07:24 tagger-params

  -rw-r----- 1 root root   172869 Sep 22 07:24 word-map

**QUESTION-1 :**
I am aware that there is no char-map file in the directory so I got the error written @ Point-3 above. So, does anyone have an opinion about how the Turkish language test could be done and the result was shared as %93,363 for Part-of-Speech for example?

**QUESTION-2:**
How can I find the char-map file for Turkish language?

**QUESTION-3:**
If there is no char-map file, must I train through tracing the steps indicated as [SyntaxNet's Obtain Data & Training](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#obtaining-data)?

**QUESTION-4:**
Is there a way to generate word-map, char-map... etc. files? Is it the well known **word2vec** approach that can be used to generate map files which will be able to be processed wt. Syntaxnet tokenizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/830 issue - it contains an (at this moment) temporary solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I can't attach patch here, so external link still would be needed.

Comment: It seems that at the link given user "xtknight" wrote the solution code. Thanks for sharing the link.